# Renewal of minor's Indian passport from the US?

Tags: passports, india, passport-renewals, minors, expired

I am in the USA and my son's Indian passport expires in a week. What should I do to renew it? If I apply through VFS, which would take 3-6 weeks to process, will it affect his stay? Or would applying on Tatkal be better?

Comment: Do you live in the USA or do you visit and do you expect to travel within the 6 weeks (plus a few extra for a buffer) the VFS takes?

Comment: What is your son's status in the US? If he is a nonimmigrant, his stay is governed by his I-94. When does his I-94 expire?